# Change text layer using psd-tools

Tags: python, psd

I need to change the content of a text layer in my PSD file. Here is my code:

```py
from psd_tools import PSDImage

psd = PSDImage.load("raw.psd")
number_layer = list(filter(lambda layer: layer.name == "some cool layer", psd.descendants()))[0]

print(number_layer.text)
number_layer.text = "Smth"
```

When I try to change the text layer, it throws
`AttributeError: property 'text' of 'TypeLayer' object has no setter`. Why? How can I change text of my layer?

Searched all Google, but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Check this discussion: https://github.com/psd-tools/psd-tools/issues/25. It may not be possible to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I searched through the source code of `psd-tools`, I found [this line](https://github.com/psd-tools/psd-tools/blob/9e469aa85f86a04b62a62cd6acddea6dc7c2daed/src/psd_tools/api/layers.py#L840) that says:

> *Currently, textual information is read-only.*

So that means you can't change the text but only read it. That justifies the error `AttributeError: property 'text' of 'TypeLayer' object has no setter`.

Same at [this line](https://github.com/psd-tools/psd-tools/blob/9e469aa85f86a04b62a62cd6acddea6dc7c2daed/src/psd_tools/api/layers.py#L865-L872) a little below the first one:

```py
@property
def text(self):
    """
    Text in the layer. Read-only.

    .. note:: New-line character in Photoshop is `'\\\\r'`.
    """
    return self._data.text_data.get(b'Txt ').value.rstrip('\x00')
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks for this answer. I found a new way to edit a text layer without psd-tools. If you was interested, you can check my answer in this question. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hello @sa1lormoon! Nice solution you gave for your problem. I see that your question is `Change text of text layer using psd-tools`, which is basically what you asked for. So technically my answer is correct because it proves that you can *not* change text layer using `psd-tools`. I leave it in your judgment if you will accept my answer as the correct one and/or upvote it. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Well, as LoukasPap said, it is impossible to change a text layer using psd-tools. I found new way to change it without psd-tools.

Here is my code:

```
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")
psd_api = app.Open("Enter here full path to PSD")
layer = psd_api.Layers["Path"].Layers["To"].Layers["Your"].Layers["Layer"]
layer.TextItem.Contents = "Some useful text"

psd_api.Save()
psd_api.Close()
```

Note that you need to install pywin32

> pip install pywin32